# Replace first JSON OBJECT of JSON ARRAY in mysql JSON FIELD

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to update a mysql JSON field which is having a Array of JSON OBJECTS.

Tried with the below query

```
select JSON_REPLACE('{"k1":[{"id":1,"name":"guna","age":34},{"id":2,"name":"guna1","age":34},{"id":3,"name":"guna2","age":34}]}','$.k1[0]','{"id":1,"name":"guna","age":34,"hi":"hi"}');
```

Updated wrong JSON value.

After updated the JSON value, the column value is having () slashes before every (") quotation. While updating the JSON column, slashes should not be added.

Comment: invalid json, try to enclose your original value with `{ ... }` - `{ "k1": [ .... ]}`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET @json := '{"k1":[{"id":1,"name":"guna","age":34},
                     {"id":2,"name":"guna1","age":34},
                     {"id":3,"name":"guna2","age":34}]}';
SET @replacement := '{"id":1,"name":"guna","age":34,"hi":"hi"}';
```

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('k1', JSON_ARRAYAGG(CAST(object AS JSON)))
FROM ( SELECT COALESCE(replacement, object) object
       FROM JSON_TABLE(@json,
                       '$.k1[*]' COLUMNS (rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
                                          object JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT @replacement replacement) replacement 
               ON object->'$.id' = replacement->'$.id' 
       ORDER BY rowid ASC LIMIT 2147483647) reconstruction;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b126516d8dd5a5ea151ed3058b037c6

---

> After updated the JSON value, the column value is having () slashes before every (") quotation.

The value used for updating is treated as string value, and all `"` are quoted. You must explicitly cast the value to JSON datatype.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ad51f6f1df4a2c1dfdd6daa25ddcb88

Comment: Updated the question, Plz check

Comment: @Gunaseelan Answer updated, issue explanation added.